# Disable /var/spool/mail message

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that does a git pull every minute. The issue is when there are no updates, it logs a message saying already update to date in /var/spool/mail/user.

```
The cron job is * * * * * cd /home/user/dir && git pull
```

Is there a way to disable it from logging that message every time it does a git pull?

The full log message is:

```
From user@localhost.localdomain  Tue Aug 28 10:21:04 2018
Return-Path: <user@localhost.localdomain>
X-Original-To: user
Delivered-To: user@localhost.localdomain
Received: by localhost.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id 2C1D3207F8E3; Tue, 28 Aug 2018 10:21:04 -0400 (EDT)
From: "(Cron Daemon)" <user@localhost.localdomain>
To: user@localhost.localdomain
Subject: Cron <user@localhost> cd /home/user/dir && git pull
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Precedence: bulk
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_SESSION_ID=701>
X-Cron-Env: <XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000>
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/user>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=user>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=user>
Message-Id: <20180828142104.2C1D3207F8E3@localhost.localdomain>
Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 10:21:04 -0400 (EDT)

Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Have the output go to a logfile or `/dev/null` instead of standard out.  Then the emails won't be generated anymore, maybe by appending `2>&1 > /dev/null`

Comment: Would setting an empty `MAILTO=` in the crontab have the desired effect?

Comment: adding `> /dev/null` supressed the emails and is working. Also read that it will still email if it errors. thanks for the help.

Comment: Just tested it out with changes, so it now only logs if there is a change with the pull or error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the /dev/null ignores the standard messages generated. It is only sending a message if there was an error.

Modified cron job
    * * * * * cd /home/user/dir && git pull > /dev/null